# Material-UI. Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, table, material-ui

Для отрисовки на клиенте данных я пользуюсь material-ui, а именно Table.

```
class RatingTable extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this); 
}
handleChange() {
    let i = 1;
    const { data } = this.state;
    return data.map(element => {
        return (
            <TableRow>
                <TableRowColumn>{i++}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{element['user.login']}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{element['hardWins']}</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
        );
    })
}
render() {
    return (
        <Table>
            <TableHeader>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableHeaderColumn>Position</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn>Login</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn>Rating</TableHeaderColumn>
                </TableRow>
            </TableHeader>
            <TableBody>
                {this.handleChange()}
            </TableBody>
        </Table>);
}
```

}

Вопрос таков: как принять данные с сервера, чтобы потом занести их в таблицу (для данного примера вопрос звучит так: как мне в this.state.data занести данные,полученные с сервера )?
Для отправки запроса использую axios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если необходимо при загрузке компонента сделать запрос к серверу, то поместите эту функцию в componentDidMount()

```
axios.get('/your-path')
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ data: response })
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

P.S: у функции map есть второй аргумент - индекс (вместо вашего созданного i счетчика)

```
return data.map((element, index) => {
    ...
}
```